# Github (SSH) via public WIFI, port 22 blocked

Tags: git, ssh, github, wifi, public

I'm currently on a public WIFI spot and I'm unable to use SSH (they probably blocked that port). However, I need that connection to do a `git push`.

```
➜ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Is it possible to bypass this restriction by setting up a SSH tunnel via port 80 and tell `github push` to use that connection? How to do that? I'm on OSX (lion). This must be a common problem?

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for Launchpad.net?

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ vim ~/.ssh/config
```

Add

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: @prtitrz any idea what's the config for heroku?

Comment: just fyi, you don't have to open the file with vim.

Comment: This is great!  But I too need to do this for heroku.  Any ideas?

Comment: Refer to https://serverfault.com/a/253314 if you are getting `Bad owner or permissions on /home/.../.ssh/config`

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for launchpad.net?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved my problem 10 years later !

Comment: probably more general-user-friendly to switch `vim` for `nano` here. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Didn't work for me, still not being able to push

Comment: `ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Answer (score 49):

The same works for Bitbucket:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
  Port  443
```

[via](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-221449711.html#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-SSHonPort443) (outdated / dead)

[via, updated](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-221449711.html#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-SSHonPort443) (2015-10-29)

Answer (score 32):

In addition to configuring it with the `~/.ssh/config` file, you can also simply include the port number in the remote URL you use.  You just have to

1. use a proper URL like `ssh://user@host:port/path` instead of the `user@host:path` shorthand; and
2. prepend the `ssh.` subdomain to `github.com`.

For instance, instead of

```
git@github.com:cdbennett/python-gitlab.git
```

use

```
ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/cdbennett/python-gitlab.git
```

Comment: This worked for me: `ssh://git@ssh.github.com/repo.git` but without the `443 port`, as that gave me an error.

Comment: But I only did this on the directory of the project with `git config --local -e`

Answer (score 11):

For gitlab, following can be added:

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
```

Source: [Alternate Gitlab SSH Port](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/)

Answer (score 3):

No need to modify the `~/.ssh/config`. You can add another remote repository via `git remote add ..`.

```
// github
git remote add ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/repo/name.git

// gitlab
git remote add ssh://git@altssh.gitlab.com:443/repo/name.git
```

Answer (score 1):

VPN (ExpressVPN) worked for me on JetBlue

Answer (score -2):

I find two ways

**First**

- **tor + torify**

After successfully Install and configure tor on system simply run this to check ssh use tor.

`torify ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com`

---

**Second**

- **tor + privoxy + corkscrew**

First configure tor from fist step.
Then install **privoxy** to convert tor SOCKS5 to HTTP proxy.

`sudo apt install privoxy`

Then install **corkscrew**

`sudo apt install corkscrew`

Place this config file in: **~/.ssh/config**

```
host *
    ProxyCommand corkscrew 127.0.0.1 8118 %h %p
```

Or with **ncat**

```
Host gitlab.com
        User git
        ProxyCommand ncat --proxy 127.0.0.1:8118 %h %p
```

Also can use **nc** instead of **ncat**

```
    ProxyCommand nc --proxy 127.0.0.1:8118 %h %p
```

Now ssh can use configured proxy.

**[Edit]**

Simpler version

Use torify before ssh command.

`torify ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com`

---

To works with **Privoxy+Tor** may need to change default configs.
For me uncomment this line in  `/etc/privoxy/config`

```
forward-socks5t   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

ssh config

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand nc --proxy 127.0.0.1:8118 %h %p
```