# How to associate GIT with SSH protocol (keys)

Tags: git, ssh, key

I am trying to create a cloud config server using cloud foundry and below JSON :

```json
{
    "count": 1,
    "git": {
        "privateKey": "****",
        "cloneOnStart": "false",
        "hostKey": "****",
        "label": "master",
        "hostKeyAlgorithm": "ssh-rsa",
        "uri": "ssh://git@bitbucketsc-ssh.emp.net:7999/proj/repo.git"
    }
}
```

I have generated a private ssh key and a public ssh key. My question is how do I tell my git to associate itself with these keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)

Comment: Also possibly https://superuser.com/a/912281

Answer (score 0):

Using "[Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/6309)" and "[GitLab (SSH) via public WIFI, port 22 blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500957/6309)", the specifc content of a `~/.ssh/config` file in your case would be:

```
Host cloud
  Hostname bitbucketsc-ssh.emp.net
  User git
  Port 7999
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cloud
```

With `~/.ssh/cloud` begin your private key, and `~/.ssh/cloud.pub` your public key.

Check it works with `ssh -T cloud`
If it asks about the ECDSA key fingerprint, answer '`y`' (yes)

Then, in your Git repo:

```
 git config set-url origin cloud:proj/repo.git
```

In that repo, any push will then use the url `ssh://git@bitbucketsc-ssh.emp.net:7999/proj/repo.git`.

Comment: where is ~/.ssh/config file? I see 'ssh_config' and 'sshd_config' config files in C:/ProgramFilesGit/etc/ssh/ folder. But i doubt if these are the files.

Comment: I see 1 empty .ssh folder without any files. I am working on a virtual machine.

Comment: If your virtual machine is the one​from which you contact your remote machine e, then copy your public/private keys and write your config file in that .ssh folder.