# Github SSH via institute proxy, port 22 as well as port 443 blocked

Tags: ssh, proxy, port

There's a stackoverflow question @ [Github (SSH) via public WIFI, port 22 blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953806/github-ssh-via-public-wifi-port-22-blocked), about blocked `port 22`, but the solution given there: `port 443` is also failing for me.

All my connections to the internet go through the Institute proxy server, and it blocks all non-standard ports. I know for a fact that `port 80` and `port 8080` are both allowed, and all my github transactions through the `https` route work perfectly.

How to solve this issue?

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com

ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

My proxy server is : `http://10.3.100.207:8080/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution to my problem. Since https works perfectly for my setup and proxy, I found a way to force `git` to use https instead of ssh, whenever it encounters ssh urls, by executing the following 2 git config commands:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

This solved the problem for me.

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5257

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your connection is *not* going through the institute proxy server, which from your description looks like a basic HTTP proxy.  Git -- and ssh -- don't know about the proxy.  You have several options:

- Access github using https, and let git know about the proxy server by setting the http.proxy configuration option.  There are instructions for doing that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server).
- Configure ssh to make use of the proxy.  This will require a tool like [corkscrew](http://agroman.net/corkscrew/) that can forward tcp connections through an http proxy (if the proxy supports the CONNECT method).  There is some useful documentation on that topic [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HTTP_tunneling).