# Unable to git clone after running config modification

Tags: git, version-control, terminal

When attempting to git clone a forked repository I'm getting the following message

```
/Users/userName/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: st
/Users/userName/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've had no issues using git until I ran this script earlier today from a post I found while trying to clone over public wifi  -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953806/github-ssh-via-public-wifi-
port-22-blocked
```

I'm pretty new to git so, I'm really at a lost of what's happening. I believe I'd must have modified my config file but I'm unsure how to correct it.

Comment: Does the forked repo also hosted in github? And did you add the SSH public key (in id_rsa.pub) in your github account? And what's your config for ssh now?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes, the repo is hosted in github. I didn't add the SSH key to my github and I'm not sure how to check my config now. Can you guide me on that  or rather tell me how to undo the mods I made from the post ?

Comment: I added an answer for how to re-generate ssh key and add the key to github for authentication, and you can have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not necessary to make additional configuration for the SSH key.

If you have made modifications in your SSH key, you can generate a new one to replace the current one:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then press enter to finish the ssh key generate.

Then **add the new generated SSH key in github**:

Github -> Settings (https://github.com/settings/keys) -> New SSH key -> name a title -> open the file `id_rsa.pub` and copy the contents of the file as the key in github (as below picture) -> Add SSH key.

[image]

Now clone again from github, it should clone successful (if there has `config` file under `.ssh` folder, the `config` file should be deleted).

Comment: I've done exactly as you've sad and read through github's SSH setup guide and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you use the repo URL format as `git@github.com:username/repo.git`? Or can you show the command you used and the whole output here?

Comment: Here is my exact input and output:  



`git clone git@github.com:userName/hrnyc-twittler.git 
Cloning into 'hrnyc-twittler'... 
/Users/userName/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: st 
/Users/userName/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Please delete the config file `/Users/userName/.ssh/config` and try again. After generate ssh key, it only generate thge three files: `id_rsa`,  `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts`. The `config` file is mainly you added manually before.

Comment: Delete the file on my local machine or from github ? If local machine - how do I do that ?

Comment: in your local machine. The `config` file is located under `/Users/userName/.ssh` directory. So just find the file and delete it in your local machine, and then clone again.

Comment: I feel really dumb. I cant find it anywhere

Comment: Uhm, but based on the output of your git clone command, seems you have the config file: `/Users/userName/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: st ...`. Did you change it as a hidden file?

Comment: No I never changed it. I can't find it searching the my files nor does it show up in my spotlif

Comment: Finally got it to work ! Thank you so much for your patience and help

Comment: Since you problem has been solved, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions :)