# Solving the a client side SSH connection error

Tags: linux, github, ssh

Essentially I cannot connect to an SSH server anymore. Whenever I try to connect I get the following error:

`ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection refused`

Note that I am able to connect from a different machine. Hence, the issue seems to be client side. Furthermore, I also cannot pull/push to git repositories that are cloned via ssh. Again, when pulling I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

It seems like I somehow nuked my SSH installations/config files. I have reinstalled SSH but this did not fix the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: When you run `ssh git@github.com`, does it return your github username?

Comment: I get the same error: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused

Comment: If you're in a corp env, complain to your IT. Otherwise, try using Cloudflare WARP.

Comment: I am on eduroam. By adding the github host to the ssh config file I am able to pull from github now. But I am still unable to connect via SSH to my private server, even when using the -p 443 argument.

Comment: Use Cloudflare WARP, if it's blocked too then setup your own OutlineVPN instance on a VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you never "connect" to github.com directly (no interactive shell)

As [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/620527/5470), "Connection refused" means

- invalid IP address for `github.com` (manual entry in `/etc/hosts` or your resolver)
- firewall along the way to github.com which blocks the ssh traffic (eg. local firewall or corporate firewall)

So is the other machine (where you do succeed) on the same network?
Check if the other machine SSH config file was not using [`ssh.gthub.com` port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081292/6309) (instead of the default `github.com:22`, typically blocked in a corporate environment).

Comment: I am on eduroam. By adding the github host to the ssh config file I am able to pull from github now. But I am still unable to connect via SSH to my private server, even when using the -p 443 argument.

Comment: @julian So firewall issue then?

Comment: But this problem persists when I use my personal phone hotspot as well. None of these things were the case 2 days ago.

Comment: @julian "connect via SSH to my private server" the same answer would apply: some kind of IP or firewall issue.